# Replace object value with values from an external array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I am working on a webchat that gets data of every message through a JSON protocol. Through ajax() I receive the following information:

```
{"id":"33","senderId":"1","message":"My fellow citizens","timestamp":"2014-10-24 11:45:04","conversationid":"2","status":"0"}
```

The **senderId** is the key to identify user's name, since if  senderId="1" it means that Michael sent the message. The array has the following names:

```
nameArray = ["Micheal", "Earvin", "Kareem", "Wilt", "Hakeem"]
```

I tried the following code, but it is not working.

```
senderId = JSON.parse(element.senderId)     
            for (var i=0; i<senderId.length; i++) {
                if (senderId[i] == 1) {
                    senderId[i] = nameArray[0];
                break;
                }
            }
```

Do you know how a way to change the senderId information according to the values of nameArray?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming element is the object `{"id":"33","senderId":"1","message":"My fellow citizens","timestamp":"2014-10-24 11:45:04","conversationid":"2","status":"0"}` and you want to replace `senderId: 1` with `Micheal`, you can

```
element.senderId = nameArray[element.senderId - 1];
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tgtnzxh7/)

Answer (score 0):

With the object that you have, you don't need a **for** loop to replace the name.
Indeed you can use a direct search into the array including and exception if the senderId doesn't exist in your nameArray.

Also, replace directly an value into the object is not a really good practice, I recommend you add another attribute to the object to have the record of the senderId if you need it in the future.

```
index = element.senderId - 1;
element.name = (index in nameArray ? nameArray[index] : "Anonymous");
```

Comment: I don't need the record of the sender in my case, so I will use Sadikhasan's and Arun's solution. But the attribute that you add is also helpful and I am going to add it too. In any case, thanks for your help eusoj :)